# Apple discussion forums unavailable?

Tags: websites

I recently purchased my first apple product and naturally a few questions popped up. However, I wasn't able to access any topics on the [Apple discussion forums](https://discussions.apple.com/) during the last week, because they seem unavailable. I tried from several devices.

What really irritates me is the fact that this isn't mentioned anywhere (except for [here](https://www.iphonetricks.org/apple-support-forums-an-unexpected-error/)) where I would have expected that this would make news quite quickly or that a company that puts so much focus on customer service as Apple would at least give some sort of status update if one of its major services was out of service for such a long time. So is it just me who has this problem or is it maybe a regional thing?

My current workaround is to use the cached sites.

Answer (score 1):

No issues here.
Nothing on Apple's status report - https://www.apple.com/uk/support/systemstatus/
A quick Google search seems to find only that one site, iphonetricks, reporting it as an issue.

If you need to check a site is down, try https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com

Bizarrely, they seem to think it's down, yet I can get straight in. Last post about 2 minutes ago & changing with each refresh.

In this kind of situation, I'd suspect it's not the site itself, it's the distribution network having issues in certain locations.

*edit*
OK, the developer community seems to have been the victim of a spam-fest. You'd think someone would be awake overnight to clean it up… but no doubt it will get tidied as soon as whoever is on call gets the call.
I've let support know. I think I fried someone's brain, their "reading from a cheat card of standard responses" was sorely tested.

*Update*
24 hours later they still haven't cleaned it up.